# How to use Listinfo to create hierarchical list

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I am trying to create a list that has another list inside it. Both lists are numbered and how do i manage the numbering

For example i am trying to create a list as follows

[image]

If you cannot see the image above then refer below

1. List 1 item 1
2. List 1 item 2

   1. List2 item 1
   2. List2 item 2
3. List 1 item 3

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK MigraDoc does not currently support nested numbered lists. One possible approach is using normal paragraphs for the outer lists (do the numbering in your code) and use automatic MigraDoc numbering for the inner lists.

Or do all the numbering (outer and inner lists) in your code.

As a workaround: use bullet lists for the outer lists and numbering only for the inner lists. This will work with MigraDoc.

Comment: Thanks but i want ordered list so there is also one more work around by using different NumberList styles which preservers its own order like(NumberList1,NumberList2,NumberList3)

Comment: @Sabareesh Kkanan: Nested numbered lists do not work AFAIK, so this is not a workaround. If you need nested numbered lists, do the numbering yourself.